# Не могу разобраться с const char*. C++

Tags: c++, указатели, char

Чтобы лучше описать мою дилемму, приведу примеры. Рассмотрим такой код.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void tostr(const int* strr) {
  cout << strr << endl;
  cout << *strr << endl;
  cout << &strr << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  int a = 55;
  int *p = &a;
  tostr(p);

  return 0;
}
```

Здесь всё поняно: const int* - это указатель. Мы передаем функции указатель на а равное 55. strr выдает адрес памяти переменной а, *strr разыменовывает адрес переменной а и выдаёт 55, &strr выдает адрес памяти переменной р со значением адреса памяти переменной а.

Но. Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void tostr(const char* strr) {
  cout << strr << endl;
  cout << *strr << endl;
  cout << &strr << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  tostr("abs");

  return 0;
}
```

const char* так же указатель. Но почему мы можем передавать функции строку, а не указатель на неё, причем даже не символ, а целую строку? Ведь если бы по такому принципу в предыдущем примере передали бы не указатель, а число, то нам бы вывалилась ошибка, мол невозможно преобразовать int в int*.

Почему здесь это работает и, самое главное, как с этим работать, ибо в этом случае strr выдает не адрес памяти, как должно было бы быть, а саму сроку?

В этом примере единственное, что работает понятно - *strr, ибо strr - указатель на char и при разыменовании ожидаемо получаем char, в данном случае - первую букву а. Хорошо, &strr то же понятно - выводит адрес переменной strr.

Comment: *"как с этим работать, ибо в этом случае strr выдает не адрес памяти, как должно было бы быть, а саму сроку"* Выдает строку, потому что `cout` так написан. Хотите адрес, делайте `(void *)str`.

Comment: Вы о перегруженных функциях в C++ знаете? Что функция для разных типов аргументов может быть разная? Вот так сделано для `char*`, поскольку традиционно, начиная с C, это - представление **строк**.

Comment: "&strr выдает адрес памяти переменной р" - это адрес переменной strr, а не p